# Interpreting factor coefficients when correlation flips

Tags: factor-models, covariance, correlation-matrix, value-investing

I am looking at mainly value and growth factor coefficients of a fund during the recent Covid market “crisis”.

I have found that said fund had a negative coefficient to value at the start of 2020 (let’s say around -0.4) and a positive growth coefficient (around 0.3).

The correlation at this time between the two factors was also negative at around -0.5.

In March 2020 when the markets nosedived the correlations of the two factors suddenly jumped to positive 0.6 as everything started moving together. At this same time the value coefficient of the same fund jumped to around -0.05, and growth fell a bit.

More recently at the end of Jan 2021 the correlation between the two factors is still high at around 0.36 (relatively high for these two factors) but it has dropped a bit and the fund’s value coefficient has basically followed it down slightly.

My question therefore is how to interpret this, it looks as though the fund has only increased exposure (reduced negative exposure) to the value factor because the correlation to other factors has likely increased ie the market is all behaving similarly.

I’m trying to ascertain if there has been a factor rotation from growth to value and whilst I see increased value exposure and reduced growth exposure how are you supposed to tell whether that was as a result of the manager’s decisions or purely the market doing wacky things in a very volatile environment?

Comment: it sounds as is your time series is relatively short and therefore sensitive to systematic market moves. "growth" and "value" stock definitions are woolly and even disputed by some top managers. Without knowing how you define these stocks and the details of your analysis I think the best anyone can do with this is offer an opinion based response.

Comment: Opinion would be fine, I am using Bloomberg’s global equity model, the main question really is how is it possible to decipher in such a correlated market whether the effects of an increased exposure to a factor are due to manager changes or market changes